# Qual a melhor forma e como implementar o armazenamento de dados globais em um aplicativo?

Tags: android

Em um aplicativo que possui autenticação, a grande maioria das vezes é necessário armazenar informações como o nome, o email e, dependendo do caso o ID deste usuário. Estas informações podem ser utilizadas em múltiplas atividades. O ID, por exemplo, pode ser utilizado como parâmetro para recuperar informações em um servidor remoto.

**Qual a melhor forma e como implementar o armazenamento de dados globais em um aplicativo?**

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a `SharedPreferences`

Para mais informações acesse a [documentação do Android](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

---

**Edit:**

Caso você entenda de inglês pode usar essa [referência do StackOverflow Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

---

**Na tradução livre:**

Para obter as preferências, use o seguinte método na sua `activity`:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
      "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Para pegar os valores:

```
String dateTimeKey = "com.example.app.datetime";

// use a default value using new Date()
long l = prefs.getLong(dateTimeKey, new Date().getTime());
```

Para editar e salvar os valores:

```
Date dt = getSomeDate();
prefs.edit().putLong(dateTimeKey, dt.getTime()).apply();
```

O local onde fica as preferências salvas do aplicativo de demostração:

```
<android-sdk-home>/samples/android-<platformversion>/ApiDemos directory
```